# Using the na.rm = TRUE option in the function for summary stats - summary()

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the summary stats of a few columns in a data frame. Some of the cells have NA values and when using the `summary()` function, I want R to exclude the values that have `NA`. I can't delete the rows because not all values in a row are `NA`s. When I use the `mean()` or `sd()` function individually with `na.rm = TRUE`, that works. But when I use the `summary()` function, `na.rm = TRUE` makes no difference.

Either of these work:

```
mean(df1[9:24,9], na.rm = TRUE) # OR
sd(df1[9:24,9], na.rm = TRUE)
```

but `summary()` does not :

```
summary(df1[9:24,9], na.rm = TRUE)
```

The `summary()` function returns the same answer whether `na.rm = TRUE` is inserted or not. Is there some way I can use the `summary()` function and also make it provide summary stats of the data subset ensuring that the `NA`s value do not have to be counted ?

Comment: As far as I can tell summary() takes out NAs by default and lists the number of NAs after the stats. This is assuming the NAs stored are not of class character.

Comment: `B <- BOD; B$demand[3] <- NA; B; summary(B)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following, with the help of subset.

```r
mean(subset(df[9:24,9],!is.na(df1[9:24,9])))
sd(subset(df[9:24,9],!is.na(df1[9:24,9])))
summary(subset(df[9:24,9],!is.na(df1[9:24,9])))
```